# Translation of “arm bike”

Tags: traduction, terminologie, sport

What is the translation of “arm bike” in French? I have seen "*vélo à bras*" and "*vélo pour bras*" but it sound weird to my ears. Is there any better translation?

Arm bike =

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As a french I would say **"vélo pour bras"**, and I think most people will understand even if they don't know the arm bike.
"Vélo à bras" sounds very weird, and I don't know any other word to describe that.

Comment: Tiens, moi c'est le contraire, je trouve « vélo pour bras » bizarre et « vélo à bras » pas plus bizarre que l'anglais « *arm bike* ».

Comment: @Gilles Je trouvais que "vélo pour bras" pouvait facilement être compris en tant que "vélo pour faire travailler les bras", alors que "vélo à bras" peut laisser une ambiguïté, le "à" marquant également l'appartenance .
Après c'est un peu "les goûts et les couleurs" !

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know this kind of machine existed... On Amazon, the portable kind (your second picture) are translated as

> Mini-vélo d'appartement pour bras et jambes
>
> Pédalier d'appartement pour bras et jambes
>
> Mini-trainer pour bras et jambes

Of all these, I quite like "mini-vélo d'appartement" which was the only one that made understand right away what the product was — like an indoor bike (*vélo d'appartement*) but smaller and more portable.

Answer (score 1):

En complément, sur *Franceterme* on a plusieurs types de [*simulateurs(-ergomètres)*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/SPOR235?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=elliptical%20trainer&francetermeSearchDomaine=0), pour l'escalade, l'escalier, le patinage ; on a aussi le *simulateur elliptique*, mais même si le cercle est une application particulière de l'ellipse, c'est plus ou moins convaincant vu l'usage qu'on en connaît. Le [vélo d'intérieur](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353751) est un [simulateur de bicyclette](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/SPOR239?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=elliptical%20trainer&francetermeSearchDomaine=0). La difficulté c'est qu'on ne fait généralement pas de la bicyclette avec les bras alors ce n'est pas exactement cette activité qu'on simule. Par ailleurs un [simulateur elliptique](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/SPOR265?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=elliptical%20trainer&francetermeSearchDomaine=0) est lui aussi muni ou équipé d'un *pédalier*, qu'on mentionne dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/22093). Un *simulateur à pédalier* peut sans doute fonctionner. On a aussi regardé du côté d'un truc comme le [(cyclo)-rameur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cyclo-/2), disons le [*pédaleur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9daleur), mais c'est déjà employé autrement...
On a aussi trouvé le *pédalier d'exercice* tout court, que je trouve plutôt adéquat finalement, et on peut préciser *pour membres supérieurs*, ou selon. Sur le site web d'une grande chaîne j'ai trouvé sur une même page, entre autres, le *cycle-exerciseur cardio de table* et le *mini vélo-exerciseur*, que je trouve un peu loufoques, quoique le préfixe *cyclo-* et le terme *exerciseur* puissent s'avérer utiles en effet. Sauf qu'à mon avis dans aucun cas ne s'agit-il d'un moyen de transport mu par la force des bras ou qui leur est destiné, ni d'un vélo, ni d'une bicyclette ; je préfère la description à l'analogie, surtout dans un contexte de consommation. Autrement le nom d'un produit relève surtout du marketing et de l'analyse des requêtes des utilisateurs à la recherche de ce genre de produit.